# Openssl AESNI-GCM table free benchmark

Tags: openssl, google-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtnKK.png)
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/modes/gcm128.c

Openssl support AESNI-GCM and there is code in github asm
aes-gcm.pl, gcm.c
I think that gcm.c use aes-gcm.pl for running gcm.c the picture is code in gcm.c
What i wandering is that the GF_mul only define with table version

I have to benchmark table free version of AESNI-128-GCM

Is there any option that disable table of GMAC? NOT s-box that HTable for multipication in GF field.
Is there only one way to modify the code of Openssl?

I benchmark several option in Openssl
make dll file for Openssl and make configure but it was hard to disable table